# JBoss 5 JMX depends-list HOW-TO

Tags: java, jboss, jmx, mbeans

I've been not able to use depends-list to know during runtime how many MBeans does the system administrator has defined for an specific topic.

My definition of the bean:

```
<mbean code="MyBean" 
      name="x:service=MyBean" xmbean-dd="">
    <xmbean>
    <class>x.MyBean</class>

    <depends-list optional-attribute-name="DynamicListBeans">
        <depends-list-element>y:service=DynamicBean,name=A</depends-list-element>
        <depends-list-element>y:service=DynamicBean,name=B</depends-list-element>
    </depends-list>
    <operation>
        <description>Refreshes dynamic beans that could be edited by the end user.
        </description>
        <name>refreshConfigurationFromJmxLists</name>
    </operation>
    </xmbean>
</mbean>
```

My class:

public class MyBean
        implements MyBeanMXBean
{

```
private List<ObjectName> dynamicListBeans;

@Override
public List<ObjectName> getDynamicListBeans() {
    return dynamicListBeans;
}

@Override
public void setDynamicListBeans(List<ObjectName> dynamicListBeans) {
    this.dynamicListBeans = dynamicListBeans;
}

public void refreshConfigurationFromJmxLists() {
    System.out.println(dynamicListBeans.size());
}
```

}

MyBeanMXBean is defining both, getter and setter for dynamicListBeans, and the operation refreshConfigurationFromJmxLists.

During execution, refreshConfigurationFromJmxLists is pringing a size of zero for the list, so JBoss didn't set the names **name=A** and **name=B**

Does anybody know if there is anything I'm misunderstanding or missing?

Help or clues will be highly appreciated, kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Current workaround is using a naming pattern and querying like next:

```
"y:service=DynamicBean,name=*"
```

Code example:

```
ObjectName objectName;
try {
    objectName = new ObjectName("y:service=DynamicBean,name=*");
} catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
}

Set<ObjectName> names = jmxProvider.queryNames(objectName,null);
```

Though it's not clear to me the use of **depends-list**, so the question is still open.